# Rename a Django Model and it's corresponding MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, django

I need to rename a Django Model in the app "myapp" from "Hotel" to "Client" and I would prefer not to use South.

I am wondering it safe to handle the changes in MySQL using queries such as the following?

> RENAME TABLE myapp_hotel TO myapp_client;
>
> RENAME TABLE myapp_hotel_sites TO myapp_client_sites;

and for tables with a Foreign Key relationship to the now Client table:

> ALTER TABLE myapp_client_sites CHANGE hotel_id client_id int(11);

Can it be as simple as that, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the table name can be done like this in MYSQL, but take into consideration you will also need to change the class names within the django code also. Else the orm will not map with the mysql database table names.

Using a tool like [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html) will ensure all the code changes are made where required within the database.

> Automatic migration creation: South can see what’s changed in your models.py file and automatically write migrations that match your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Matt. Have taken all of the above into consideration. Any refs to the old 'hotel' nomenclature have been obliterated from the codebase. Testing as we speak.